# Where can I find the java truststore file?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, truststore

I have added a certificate with    keytool    . Now I have to locate the associated truststore-file. Where do I find it?

Comment: What have you added your certificate to? Are you looking for the *default* truststore or perhaps another one used by your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'an associated truststore file'. The file you have added the certificate to *is* the truststore.